# Scrolling to the Bottom of a Bootstrap(2.3.2) Modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, twitter-bootstrap-2

Hello I am trying to scroll to the bottom of a bootstrap modal onclick. So far I haven't had any success but moving the back of the page around. Any ideas on what to do?

I've looked at: 
[Autoscrolling a bootstrap modal on modal('show')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388002/autoscrolling-a-bootstrap-modal-on-modalshow)
[Twitter bootstrap scrollable modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899676/twitter-bootstrap-scrollable-modal)

HTML

```
<div id="groupModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 id="groupName"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
            </div>
            <div id="interestedDiv" class="collapse">
                <form id="interestedForm">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Interested Form</legend>
                        <input id="firstNameField" class="interestedField" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
                        <input id="lastNameField" class="interestedField" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                        <input id="emailField" class="interestedField" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        <input id="phoneField" class="interestedField" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        <button style="margin-bottom: 10px !important;" id="interestedSubmitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-custom" disabled="true">Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <a id="interestedBtn" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#interestedDiv"><i id="chevron" class="icon-chevron-right"></i> I'm Interested!</a>
        </div>
        <!--        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-custom">Close</a>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#interestedBtn').click(function(event){
    if($('#interestedDiv').hasClass('in')) {
        $('#chevron').attr('class', 'icon-chevron-right');
    } else {
        $('#chevron').attr('class', 'icon-chevron-up');
        $('#firstNameField').focus();
        $('#groupModal').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#groupModal').position().top + $('#groupModal').height()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Make use of hidden elements as targets.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Go through [**this**](http://www.tympanus.net/scrollupdown/#fn1.0) link.

Comment: I tried this:  
$('#groupModal').animate({  
    scrollBottom: $('#scrollToSpot').position().bottom  
});
  
Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I did it without using `javascript`.

<kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalkin/KLDP5/)**</kbd>

HINT: add `<a href="#"> <button /> </a>`

Comment: I would have liked to find a solution with Javascript but this worked for me.